# How may I customize app suggestions in iOS

Tags: ios, info.plist, build-settings

I would like to customise [App Suggestions](https://www.phonearena.com/news/App-suggestions-in-iOS-10-how-they-work-whats-changed-how-to-disable-them_id89219) in iOS programatically.

It usually says Good Morning and my app name.

Is it possible that I configure it to say something other than "good morning"?

Can I control when and where it appears?

I couldn't find much information in this regard.

Thanks,

Elstine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't modify** App Suggestions from an application, as that content is outside of the scope of an app's sandbox.

"Good Morning" appears there because the App Suggestion feature detected that you usually use a particular app in the morning and greets you with an according message. Those strings come directly from this feature and are not app-dependent; therefore, they can't be changed as of now.

Comment: are you sure about that .. because too me.. it sounds like 3D touch ?

Comment: It may be customizable later like 3D Touch options (although I doubt that this would happen in the near future), but it isn't currently.